# d3 prevent firing of mouseout on contextmenu

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, extjs, dom-events

I have created an SVG in an extjs panel. When I right click on the SVG element, mouseover event is also fired which changes the SVG but I want the SVG elemnt as it was before right click. So that I can export the previous SVG to image rather than the changed one.

Here is my sample code:

```
var path = this.svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(partition.nodes(dataset))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("stroke","#fff")
        .style("stroke-width","1px")        
        .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            return d.parent? getCurrColor(d) : "#FFFFFF"; 
        })
        .on("click", click)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) { return mouseover(d, this);})
        .on("mousemove", function(d) { return mousemove(d, this);})
        .on("mouseout", function(d){ return mouseout(d, this);});
```

On the contextmenu of the body of panel, this is the code:

```
this.body.on('contextmenu', this.optionsMenu,this);

optionsMenu:function{
    var me = this;
    var xyArr = eventObject.getXY();
    eventObject.stopEvent();
    eventObject.preventDefault();
    var menuItems=[];

    var emailItem = {
            text:'Save as image',
            scope:this,
            handler:function(){
                //save as image
            },          
    };

    menuItems.push(emailItem);

   var menu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
                items : menuItems
    });     

        menu.showAt(eventObject.getXY());
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `event.stopPropagation()` in your contextmenu listener?

Comment: stopPrapagation doesnt bubble down..so on body context menu, it doesnt stop firing for svg element.

Comment: oh.. Yeah.. Mouse pointer target becomes the new menu item created which results in mouseout listener of SVG. So why don't you try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the context menu at XY position of right click event, mouse pointer targets to the new menu item. This results in mouseout event of SVG.

So the solution for this issue would be to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` listeners instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` listeners.